# get each words from a string array + color words

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, split

I'm stuck to get each words from a string array
here is part of code :

```
String wordS[] = mystring.split(" ");
```

then I'd like to get each word stocked in wordS[] ,and after convert each words stocked in wordS[] into String

example :

```
mystring = " hi everyone how are you "

String[] wordS = mystring.split(" ");

String word1 = word1 from wordS[](Hi)

String word2 = word2 from wordS[](eeryone)

String word3 = word3 from ... for max 20 strings wich contain 1 word
```

EDIT :

here is my code :

```
String txt = tv.getText().toString();

                Pattern mat = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\^)([^0-9]+[0-9]+)|([^^0-9]+$)");
                Matcher m = mat.matcher(txt);
                while (m.find())
                {
                    String match = m.group();
                    String n= match.replaceFirst("^[^0-9]+", "");
                    if (n.length() >= 1)
                    {

                        int i = Integer.parseInt(n);

                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                s = "<font color ='black'>";
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                s = "<font color ='red'>";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                String green = "#7CFC00";
                                s = "<font color ='" + green + "'>";
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                String  gold ="#FFD700";
                                s = "<font color ='" + gold + "' >";
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                s = "<font color ='blue' >";
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                String cyan ="#00FFFF";
                                s = "<font color ='" + cyan + "' >";
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                String magenta ="#FF00FF";
                                s = "<font color ='" + magenta + "' >";
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                String peru ="#FFC0CB";
                                s = "<font color ='" + peru + "' >";
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                String gray ="#808080";
                                s = "<font color ='" + gray + "' >";
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                String orange ="#FFA500";
                                s = "<font color ='" + orange + "' >";
                                break;

                            default:
                                s = "<font color ='white'>";
                        }

                        String replace = match.replaceFirst("[0-9]+$", ""); 
                        String[] wordS = replace.split(" ");
                        showf.setText(Html.fromHtml(s + "" + replace + "</font>"));


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showf.setText(match.replaceFirst("[0-9]+$", ""));
                    }
                }
```

This function is to colorize part of string , it will detect if the user typed ^test2 <-- "2" = int which assign a color .if y type : ^blablabla5 it will return cyan text color . work fine but now I want to update my function example if I type : ^word4 ^secondword6
my function will only return the last word but I want all the words typed by the user 
have you an idea please?

Comment: What's the point of creating as much number of variables as there are elements in the array? In fact, you can't do that. You can't create variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the usage of String array

```
String [] words = mystring.split(" ");
```

Then use the index to get each string. Eg: words[i]  where `i` is the index.
So instead of declaring a separate `String` for each, you may just use `words[0]`, `words[1]` and so on without declaring addition variables. Its same as doing the following:

```
String s1 = words[0];
String s2 = words[1];
...
```

Regarding showing in a `TextView`, its not clear what you want to show in the `TextView`.

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(Your_Textviw_ID); // you  might have declared it in an XML somewhere. 
text.setText(the_sring_you_want_to_set_it_to);
```

Comment: how to use index @Shobhit Puri

Comment: @RohitJain I am sorry you felt so. I just thought that asker's intention was to be able to split the statement and use the individual strings. So I answered accordingly. Can you kindly add your input to it, if you feel differently? Thanks.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri. My view point is, there is no point in worrying about creating variables, once OP has an array. He can index array to get the values.

Comment: @RohitJain Perfectly valid view point. I agree. I mentioned it in the answer assuming that he/she seems to be unaware of that.

Comment: @Clyx I think that seems to be a new question. You can start a new question with your issue. Post the link if possible. :)